# How do I Add an application icon to a main menu in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I'd like to add an icon to the main menu of my application to the side of the File, Edit, View, ... items, 
not to the MenuItem (so, not like the scissors for Cut or the floppy disk for Save).

How should I modify my xaml project to be able to load a picture in the main Menu?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the icon on the top left in the **title** bar?

Comment: where exactly you want that ? post a pic ..

Comment: Suppose I want to place the fox icon in this picture next to File Edit View History... and NOT next to "Finance Policies and Procedures". http://blogs.adobe.com/tcs/files/2011/04/webhelp_output_titlebar.png